# C++ Target object lifecycle

Tags: c++, antlr4

I am trying to modify the runtime to not use shared pointers and no locks. 
I did replace all of them to use new operator instead, so far so good, the runtime still operates correctly, but... there is a very large number of memory leaks (not surprising).
What is the lifecycle of objects like ATNConfig? Where would be a safe place to delete them?
Note, I also made the generated parser use non static ATN so I don't need the locks in multithread context.

Here is an example of a leak I get:

```
==4747== 54,736,648 (53,672,160 direct, 1,064,488 indirect) bytes in 1,118,170 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1,519 of 1,519
==4747==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4747==    by 0xAE24F0: antlr4::atn::ParserATNSimulator::getEpsilonTarget(antlr4::atn::ATNConfig*, antlr4::atn::Transition*, bool, bool, bool, bool) (ParserATNSimulator.cpp:1050)
==4747==    by 0xAE1D01: antlr4::atn::ParserATNSimulator::closure_(antlr4::atn::ATNConfig*, antlr4::atn::ATNConfigSet*, std::unordered_set<antlr4::atn::ATNConfig*, antlr4::atn::ATNConfig::Hasher, antlr4::atn::ATNConfig::Comparer, std::allocator<antlr4::atn::ATNConfig*> >&, bool, bool, int, bool) (ParserATNSimulator.cpp:894)
```

Comment: Why do you want to replace smart pointers by raw pointers? I usually try the opposite (as I'm tired about all the problems I had before I learnt about smart pointers).

Comment: I hope you are aware that the question you ask is the exact one shared pointers were trying to solve

Comment: If we had a simple answer to your question we wouldn't need to invent smart pointers in the first place.

Comment: To Scheff: speed is my motivation

Comment: To StoryTeller: I know, but pool of objects are generally better, although one has to explicitly return the objects to the pool, and Google tcmalloc (that I'm using) gives very good  new/delete performance.

Answer (score 1):

I thought intensely about a solution without smart pointers for the ANTLR4 C++ runtime, because they make processing slower, but couldn't find one. The DFA and particularly the ATNConfig instances are organized like a mesh, referencing each other. There's no central instance that manages them. They are (Java like) created and destroyed in many places during prediction.

What could help instead is to replace the shared pointers in function calls by raw pointers, in cases where that doesn't affect the lifetime of those pointers. But I doubt this will bring more than a few percent speed win.

Comment: Hi Mike, I agree, the local change to raw pointers is not going to be significant.

Comment: Keeping shared pointers but making dedicated pools of objects, specifically for the DFA and ATNConfig objects that seems to be the more dynamic ones, might be a venue. The pools would have to be per thread. std::allocate_shared seems to fit the bill.

Comment: @AlainMarcel I'd love to see a pull request once you found a better way of managing the memory in the ANTLR4 runtime. Currently everything is close to the Java reference implementation, but we can certainly apply some optimizations that better fit C++.

Comment: Would you be open to use something like this?  It uses TBB: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161614/is-there-an-open-source-thread-safe-c-object-pool-implementation , if not, there are many object pools out there, we will need to find one that fits with the ANTLR licensing

Comment: Just throwing in an object pool won't cut it (but I thought about such an approach, of course). You would need to restructure how classes are managed in general.