# std::shared_ptr with custom deleter?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I want to implement an `object pool`, so I need to manage the memory of the object myself. So I thought of customizing the deleter of shared_ptr to realize object recycling. Below is an example ref to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161614/is-there-an-open-source-thread-safe-c-object-pool-implementation)

```cpp
    template <typename T>
    class object_pool
    {
        std::shared_ptr<tbb::concurrent_bounded_queue<std::shared_ptr<T>>> pool_;
    public:
        object_pool() 
        : pool_(new tbb::concurrent_bounded_queue<std::shared_ptr<T>>()){}

        // Create overloads with different amount of templated parameters.
        std::shared_ptr<T> create() 
        {         
              std::shared_ptr<T> obj;
              if(!pool_->try_pop(obj))
                  obj = std::make_shared<T>();

              // Automatically collects obj.
              return std::shared_ptr<T>(obj.get(), [=](T*){pool_->push(obj);}); 
        }
    };
```

### question

Since the std::shared_ptr's deleter does not release the memory, So how do I release the memory in the "~object_pool" function?

Comment: The shared pointers in pool probably just want to be normal shared pointers with standard deleters. You'd then transfer those objects to new shared pointers with your custom deleters in `create`

Answer (score 1):

The memory is owned by `std::shared_ptr<T> obj`

The returned `std::shared_ptr<T>(obj.get()` will not indeed explicitly delete the object, but the deleter lambda captures `std::shared_ptr<T> obj` by value, so the deleter of the returned pointer will own the object, until it is tranfered to `pool_`.

So the memory is either owned by `std::shared_ptr<T> obj;` from `create()` or by `shared_ptr<T>` in `pool_`. It is then freed when `pool_` is cleared.

---

Use of `shared_ptr` is suboptimal here. Looks like the example was created before C++11 move-semantic was adopted. This can be rewritten so that `pool_` and returned pointer deleter contained `unique_ptr`.